# MySQL select multiple values from column

Tags: select, mysql

Here is the table

```
ID    WHO    FRUIT
1     Adam   Apple
2     Adam   Lemon
3     Eve    Apple
4     Adam   Grape
5     God    Papaya
6     Eve    Melon
```

How do I get all persons who have apple and lemon: in this case, so that I get the result Adam?

Furthermore, I want all persons who have apple and lemon or melon, so I would get Adam and Eve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a self join on the table.

First one:

```
SELECT t1.who
FROM   table t1
JOIN   table t2
ON     t1.who = t2.who
WHERE
       t1.fruit = 'Apple'
AND    t2.fruit = 'Lemon'
```

Second one:

```
SELECT t1.who
FROM   table t1
JOIN   table t2
ON     t1.who = t2.who
WHERE
       t1.fruit = 'Apple'
AND    ( t2.fruit = 'Lemon' OR t2.fruit = 'Melon' )
```

Comment: The t1.fruit != t2.fruit condition is rather implied by the next two conditions, in both queries.  No harm done - but not much good either.